# Print stored procedure message directly to Java console

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a stored procedure where I am using

```
dbms_output.put_line(' output' || outVar);
```

I want to print same output directly in Java console (directly from stored proc) without using below code to get `outVar` :

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, String);
system.out.println(callableStatement.getString());
```

Comment: _Why_ don't you want to use an `OUT` variable in the procedure? How could the variable move over JDBC otherwise?

Comment: You can't.  But your goal doesn't seem to make sense.  A stored procedure runs on the database server.  It can only write to a memory buffer on the client.  If you don't expose an API to return that data to the client (such as using an OUT parameter), the client can't possibly access memory that is internal to the server.  You could come up with a more obscure/ complicated method to return the data but I don't see why you'd want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your procedure to a function as:

```
FUNCTION SOME_FUNCTION
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
 -- Do some processing here....
 RETURN 'output:' || ....;
END;
```

Back in java land:

```
CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{? = call SOME_FUNCTION}");
cs.registerOutParameter(1, String);
cs.executeUpdate();
system.out.println(cs.getString(1));
```

There is no other way.  You got ORACLE, you got the IDE console. There is no relationship between the two. To get data back from the database, you have to use a function to return a value, you could argue that returning values as out parameters is the same thing, and while both WILL get a value back, your code will be much more intuitive to others.  It says, this call returns something.

That said, you can call the method in SQL developer and print as follows:

```
DECLARE
    result varchar2;
BEGIN
    result := SOME_FUNCTION;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE(result);
END;
```

Comment: check this out - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:45027262935845

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for debug purposes, you can just use a table to store the value you want:

```sql
...
BEGIN   
    UPDATE MY_TABLE 
    SET MY_COLUMN = 'hello'
    WHERE ID = 123456;
    COMMIT;    
    -- Rest of stored procedure code
END;
```

Then check the value in that table after you run the stored procedure.